# How can I simulate deadlock in SQL Server nested transactions?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

Actually I would like to find answers for the following situation:
Let's say I have a stored procedure (`Usp1`) which at some moment calls an other stored procedure (`usp2`). Each of the stored procedures is a transaction. So there are nested transactions.

1. Can a deadlock occur in nested transactions while modifying the same table from 2 different sql server sessions?
2. Are there any possibilities of conflicts which leads to deadllock between the inner and outer transactions of the same stored procedure in a single session?

Examples would be really appreciated.

Comment: Different sessions are needed for both blocking and deadlocking.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't actually have a concept of "nested transactions"... If you do `BEGIN TRAN` 1000 times. This will increase the `@@trancount` to 1000 but there is still only one transaction. You can then do 900 `COMMIT`s to decrease the `@@trancount` to 100. Then, a single `ROLLBACK` will roll back EVERYTHING, including what you thought was "committed".

Comment: You're asking if a session will deadlock itself in this situation? A session will only deadlock on itself due to certain scenarios of parallelism (like what happens when using `MERGE`), but not due to something that happened in a prior statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman intra-query deadlocks within a single session do happen--just not in the scenario the OP describes.